# What Views can a Controller Action return?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC 5, does every Controller Action have to return a View with the same name as the Controller?

Here's my project. Have a webpage which contains a button to upload an image to a database. When the webpage is loaded, I want it to display a list of all the images that have already been uploaded. So, the Index (default) Action for this Controller loads the images from the database, and returns the Index View, which in turn displays the list of images:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Load the images from the database
    var images = GetImages();

    return View(images);
}
```

On that same webpage, there is a button which allows the user to upload an image to the database. That button calls the Upload Action, which uploads the file based upon the "file" and "folder" arguments that are passed, and then finally returns the Index View again:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file, string folder)
{
    // Upload the file from the specified folder
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...

    return Index();
}
```

However, when a user clicks on this upload button, the following error message is displayed:

```
The view 'Upload' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations
```

But I am not trying to render a View called "Upload" - I am trying to render the view called "Index", which is why I have the line `return Index();`.

Any help on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: It's a good idea to redirect the user after a POST method. Take a look at [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

Although *Vitaliy* and *Nathan A* provided adequate answers, I wanted to explain **why** your initial approach doesn't work because it's a great question and doesn't seem to make sense.

To get our answer we have to look at the [ASP.NET MVC source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest).

Before we get to that let's walk through your code.

1. The user visits (or POSTS to) `/Controller/Upload`
2. We do some logic and then return `Index()`
3. `Index()` is a method that returns its own view with its own model
4. MVC fails to find 'Upload' view and throws an exception

*What went wrong?*

Firstly know that `Index()` **is** being called and returned successfully. The model object is also being passed to the view (if one is found).

When you return `Index()`, it is returning [View()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460331(v=vs.118).aspx) which is an inherited method from the Controller class which returns a [ViewResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresult(v=vs.118).aspx).

A ViewResult inherits from [ViewResultBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresultbase(v=vs.118).aspx).

When a ViewResult is being returned it calls [ExecuteResult()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresultbase.executeresult(v=vs.118).aspx).

Taking a look at the source code for `ExecuteResult()`:

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
    if (context == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ViewName))
    {
        this.ViewName = context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
    }
    ViewEngineResult viewEngineResult = null;
    if (this.View == null)
    {
        viewEngineResult = this.FindView(context);
        this.View = viewEngineResult.View;
    }
    TextWriter output = context.HttpContext.Response.Output;
    ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(context, this.View, this.ViewData, this.TempData, output);
    this.View.Render(viewContext, output);
    if (viewEngineResult != null)
    {
        viewEngineResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(context, this.View);
    }
}
```

The key here is `context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action")`. This code gets the action name so that a view can be found and rendered. Note that it is using a [ControllerContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllercontext(v=vs.118).aspx).

Because of this, your action is actually set when the `Upload()` method is first called. If you step through your `Index()` method you will see that calling `context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action")` will return the string `"Upload"`.

This is because, within the context of the user request, the action is in fact Upload (that's the page they requested).

### Fun fact

If you return `Index()` and that method happens to alter the ViewBag (ViewData) then the ViewData will be altered regardless of what is rendered.

If your `Upload()` does this:

```
ViewBag.Test = "Upload method";
```

And you return `Index()` and your `Index()` does this:

```
ViewBag.Test = "Index method";
```

Then the value of `Test` will be *"Index method"*.

Comment: The short answer is: use `RedirectToAction()`.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the documentation on the View method.  It has several arguments you can provide, one of them being a string of the name of the view, but you always use the View() method if you want to return a view.

However, if you don't want to use the default View name (being the name of the action method), simply use a string to specify a new name like so:

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file, string folder)
{
    return View("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do either:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

or:

```
return View("Index");
```

Comment: The difference being that with a redirect, the url on the browser would actually match your index page, where with the view method, you'd see your index page, but the URL would still be "upload".  For less confusion, I'd suggest that the redirect is the better option.

Comment: Thanks, that's works well. However, I'm still confused as to why my method didn't work. My Upload function is expecting an ActionResult return value, and it returns Index(), which itself returns an ActionResult value. So, the function is getting it's expected View eventually - why is this causing an error?

Answer (score 0):

Just a side-note, you're not constrained to show views from the View folder for the controller name. You can do

```
public ActionResult something()
{
    return View("../OtherView/somethingElse");
}
```